# Reversing a list using foldr

Tags: list, scheme, fold

How can you define a function to reverse a list as only a single call to foldr?

It should look like this

```
(define (rev l)
    (foldr ___________________________
```

This is a practice exam question, for which the teacher decided not to give answers for -.-

Comment: We expect you to have attempted to solve this problem by yourself rather than asking the community to arrive at a complete solution for you. When you've got some code to show us that demonstrates some effort by you (even if it's wrong) please update your question and flag to re-open. Thanks.

Comment: This teacher wouldn't happen to be one Ana Milanova, would it?

Answer (score 1):

It's super-easy if you read the [documentation](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/pairs.html#%28def._%28%28lib._racket/private/list..rkt%29._foldr%29%29) first. You'll discover that `foldr` receives three parameters:

- A procedure to be called, receives as parameters (in that order) the current element that's being processed from the input list and the accumulated answer so far
- An initialization value
- The list to process

Now think about it for a moment. If we're going to build a new list from scratch, what could be the initial value? and how would we construct the list, what procedure can be used for sticking together the elements? Of course, the last parameter is the input list.

The only tricky part is defining the procedure. Given that you receive an element and the accumulated answer so far, how can you put that element at the end of the accumulator? Hint: this is the general structure of the procedure, fill-in the missing part:

```
(lambda (element accumulator) <???>)
```

Extra hint: by reading the documentation, you'll understand that `foldr` processes the input list from left-to-right. To see this, pass `cons` as the first parameter to `foldr` and you'll see that it simply copies the input list as-is. Contrast this with `foldl`, which appears to process the list from right-to-left - if you pass `cons` as the first parameter to `foldl` the newly created list will be reversed.

Comment: I think you got the left and right mixed up. Implementing reverse using `foldl` is trivial, but with `foldr`, it's not.

Comment: @ChrisJester-Young no, it's not mixed. That's what the OP's exercise is all about - contrived and inefficient, but not _that_ difficult using the right list procedures